# Convert unichar to String?

Tags: swift

I'm getting a `unichar` type returned from `NSString`'s instance method `characterAtIndex(Int)` and I want to compare it with a Swift type `String`. Is there an easy way to do this?

```
var str = "#ffffff"
var unichar = (str as NSString).characterAtIndex(0)
var unicharString = // Perform magic
var containsHash = unicharString == "#" // Should return `true`
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not `var containsHash = str.hasPrefix("#")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str:String = "#ffffff"
var unichar = str[str.startIndex]
var unicharString = "\(unichar)"
var containsHash = unicharString == "#"
```

Comment: I'm asking the easiest questions tonight, huh?

Comment: This one's actually a bit strange. Getting the characterAtIndex of an NSString essentially returns an Int value, which you cannot directly compare to a Swift String. Is there a particular reason you were using characterAtIndex?

Comment: Well, at first, I tried `str[0]` which didn't work. I wasn't aware of `String.Index` so I just used `NSString.characterAtIndex`. I also was not aware that String actually has access to NSString's entire API (with `NSString.length` being renamed to `utf16count`)

Comment: Hmm yeah, the character handling in Swift is pretty different. In obj-c all chars were the same bit-size but that's no longer the case in Swift. You can use the NSString API but I think it's better to avoid it whenever possible.

Comment: Definitely agree! Oddly, `String.characterAtIndex(Int)` is reporting an error saying it does not exist, even though it should be available [(according to the first note in Apple's String documentation)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html).

Comment: That definitely seems to be a bug!

Comment: That's not a bug. `String` doesn't have `characterAtIndex` method. Only `NSString` does. However, you can always cast `NSString` to `String` or viceversa. The 3rd variable `unicharString` is completely unnecessary, just `unichar == "#"` is enough.

Comment: This does not work for me anymore using Swift 2.0. @ishkawa's answer works, though.

Answer (score 10):

Use UnicodeScalar to convert unichar into String or Character (element of String).

```
var str = "#ffffff"
var unichar = (str as NSString).characterAtIndex(0)
var unicharString = Character(UnicodeScalar(unichar))
var containsHash = unicharString == "#"
```

- unichar is an alias of UInt16 (`typealias unichar = UInt16`).
- UnicodeScalar has `init(_ v: UInt16)`.
- Character (element of String) has `init(_ scalar: UnicodeScalar)`.

Note: String also has `init(count: Int, repeatedValue c: UnicodeScalar)`, but this is not suitable for this case.

Comment: And `String(UnicodeScalar(unichar))` for the string conversion.